# Append a row to a sorted table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, tablesorter

How can I add a row to a dynamically-generated table but have the id of the tr's numerically ordered?

For example:

```
<table id="myDataTable">
<tr id="5143">
 <td>Data Cell 1</td>
 <td>Data Cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr id="5144">
 <td>Data Cell 1</td>
 <td>Data Cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr id="5149">
 <td>Data Cell 1</td>
 <td>Data Cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr id="5150">
 <td>Data Cell 1</td>
 <td>Data Cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How could I add a tr with an id of 5145 so that it was below 5143 but above 5149? I would like a solution that doesn't involve a plugin, if that's possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would sort it... but idk if this is efficient or not

```
//arr is an array of the row id's
//row is the row being inserted
idx = arr.sort().indexOf(row.id) - 1;
$(row).insertAfter($("#myDataTable tr")[idx])
```

e.g.

http://jsfiddle.net/Dq37V/

Comment: This does work, Thank you Joseph! Another version that includes a scenario in which Orolo's method wouldn't work for: http://jsfiddle.net/Dq37V/1/

Answer (score 2):

You could loop through the tr's and compare; if it is larger then the current id, then add it.

Example:

```
$('#myDataTable tr').each(function(index, Element) {
    if (5145 > Number($(Element).attr('id'))) {
        $(Element).after('<tr id="5145"><td>Data Cell 1</td></tr>');
    }
});
```

Comment: I know. Provided. Thanks James.

Comment: Thank you Orolo! If 5144 existed in the list wouldn't this method insert the row above 5144 and below 5143, thus making the list incorrect .. 5143 .. 5145 .. 5144? I modified my answer to accommodate this situation

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$('#myDataTable tr').each(function() { .. }` 
for going through on table's tr then if you find to match just use jquery after function to add new row just after right tr 
`